# Creating Database in iOS Application

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I developed an application in iOS using qt. I am trying to create a DB `sqlitedata.db`. But DB is not getting created.

I have used

```
QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::StandardLocation type)
```

to get the correct path.

The path returned from `qDebug()` was:

> /var/mobile/Applications/262093E8-F9A7-4624-9559-FB3C6BF393E5/Library/Application Support/sqlitedata.db

But inside the Library folder, there is no folder named Application Support and no DB.
Please help with a solution to create a DB and read / update the DB through application.

Comment: Please share piece of code that you get the error from

Comment: Ironically there is no error . But db is missing with the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the path returned from QStandardPath actually exists. If it doesn't, than create it first.